# Geofencing android app with ability to create custom waypoints

Tags: android, gps, gis

For bike and running purpose, i'd like to find a GPS app that automatically cut a track into several tracks based on custom waypoints.

The idea would be :

1. Create some lines (at least two points) being the waypoints (WP1, WP2, etc...)
2. Record a GPS track
3. Each time a waypoint would be crossed, the app would automatically create a new track.

At the end, it would be possible to compare my time between each waypoints, with for example this kind of matrix :

```
+------------+-------+-------+-----+
|  portion   | run#1 | run#2 | ... |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+
| WP1 to WP2 | 10:12 | 11:00 | ... |
| WP2 to WP3 | 5:06  | 5:30  | ... |
| ...        | ...   | ...   | ... |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+
```

I've already written a python script doing this based on gpx files, but I'd like to see it in relative real time.

Do you know if this kind of app exists ? Thank you !